# How to print effective webpack build config to the console?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a complex webpack config setup (merge of dynamic settings over multiple config files) and I would like to see what is the final config that webpack uses, i.e. the result of the merge of all of those and the default settings.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works for me with webpack 4.x:

```javascript
let config = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    { // anonymous plugin
      apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tapAsync('MyCustomBeforeRunPlugin', function(compiler, callback) {
          // debugger
          console.dir(compiler.options)
          callback()
        })
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

When you uncomment the `debugger` statement and run the build with `--inspect-brk` flag (`node --inspect-brk run-webpack.js`), you can also see it in Chrome devtools on `chrome://inspect/` page (useful to inspect the functions and object instances that are not serializable to the console).

Answer (score 7):

what worked for me well also is, I created all the configs I want before the export statement and then exported a function which can console and return the configs

```
module.exports = () => {
  // I have two configs to export and wanted to see the rules
  // you may not see the nested objects then you have to console log them
  // directly

  console.log(config[0].module.rules);
  console.log(config[1].module.rules);
  return config;
};
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, not sure why it was voted down.  There is no magic the the webpack config that requires a tap into webpack to dump it.  And with webpack 4, the code in the answer by @jakub.g just didn't work.

Comment: This works for me! This is a smart solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use the [webpack-config-dump-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-config-dump-plugin)

There are installation and use instructions on the npm page.